# Get the same ID and return the higher one from one Object PHP Array Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

i have an Array Object like this :

```
[
    {'id' : 1, 'school' : 'Harvard', 'score' : 90},
    {'id' : 2, 'school' : 'LA University', 'score' : 50},
    {'id' : 4, 'school' : 'Cairo', 'score' : 90},
    {'id' : 3, 'school' : 'Monster University', 'score' : 70},
    {'id' : 4, 'school' : 'Cairo', 'score' : 30},
    {'id' : 1, 'school' : 'Harvard', 'score' : 80},
]
```

and my expected result is like this :

```
[
    {'id' : 1, 'school' : 'Harvard', 'score' : 90},
    {'id' : 2, 'school' : 'LA University', 'score' : 50},
    {'id' : 3, 'school' : 'Monster University', 'score' : 70},
    {'id' : 4, 'school' : 'Cairo', 'score' : 90},
]
```

i tried some function like `array_unique` and `array_intersect` but the result is different than i expected

so my purpose is get the higher score from the same record when the record have multiple record

hope you guys can help me

thanks

Comment: post your query please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by using Lodash

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [
  { 'id': 1, 'school': 'Harvard', 'score': 90 },
  { 'id': 2, 'school': 'LA University', 'score': 50 },
  { 'id': 4, 'school': 'Cairo', 'score': 90 },
  { 'id': 3, 'school': 'Monster University', 'score': 70 },
  { 'id': 4, 'school': 'Cairo', 'score': 30 },
  { 'id': 1, 'school': 'Harvard', 'score': 80 },
]

var result = _(data)
  .orderBy(['id', 'school'], ['asc', 'desc'])
  .uniqBy('id')
  .value();

console.log(result);
</script>
```

Comment: But your array doesn't look like php array

Comment: hmm sorry, i think i'd paste the json_encode result ^_^

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to this, but this does work with your example data set.  I adapted this from a Youtube tutorial by "TUTORIALS AND TRAINING" on call back functions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jrZhkphCng

This usort() method is also demonstrated in the link that @Sameera referenced.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){

  if([$a['id'], $a['score']] < [$b['id'], $b['score']]){

    return -1;

  }elseif([$a['id'], $a['score']] > [$b['id'], $b['score']]){

      return 1;

    } else {

      return 0;

     }

});


for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){

  if($array[$i]['id'] != $array[$i+1]['id']){

  $results[$i]['id']      = $array[$i]['id'];
  $results[$i]['school']  = $array[$i]['school'];

  }
}

array_reverse($results);

json_encode($results);  //<--This will output a json encoded string.
```

This will output an array like this:

```
     Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [school] => Harvard
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [school] => LA University
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [school] => Monster University
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [school] => Cairo
        )

)
```

Or if you use the json_encode() a json encoded string like this:

```
{"1":{"id":1,"school":"Harvard"},"2":{"id":2,"school":"LA University"},"3":{"id":3,"school":"Monster University"},"5":{"id":4,"school":"Cairo"}}
```

Comment: one question, how to make the result to be like this ? `array( array('id' =>'1', 'school' =>'aaa'), array('id' =>'2', 'school'=>'LA University')`?

Comment: @Muhammad Bima Pramadinata Please see updated answer.

Comment: @Muhammad Bima Pramadinata  I updated my answer again.  I added the json_encode.  That will give you a json encoded string to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = 'Your array of objects';

usort($data, function($a, $b)
{
if($a->id == $b->id)
    return $b->score - $a->score;
return strcmp($a->id, $b->id);
});

$known = array();
$finalData = array_filter($data, function ($val) use (&$known) {
$unique = !in_array($val->id, $known);
$known[] = $val->id;
return $unique;
});

print_r($finalData); // your desired array
```

Comment: does `usort()` support for php 5.3 ?

Comment: Yes it works, you can test there http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/